# Installing NVIDIA driver for Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to install the nvidia-driver for Debian.

I've read everywhere that the correct solution is to run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver` and the driver should install itself without problems.

However this command leaves me with the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver : Depends: nvidia-driver-libs (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-driver-bin (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-vdpau-driver (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 375.82-1~deb9u1)
                 Depends: nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) or
                          nvidia-kernel-375.82
                 Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 375) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: nvidia-persistenced
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried installing the missing dependencies (like `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-libs`) but this just results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-libs : Depends: libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libgl1-nvidia-glx (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: nvidia-egl-icd (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libegl1-nvidia (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-i386
                      Recommends: libopengl0-glvnd-nvidia but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libglx-nvidia0 (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libgles-nvidia1 (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libgles-nvidia2 (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libnvidia-cfg1 (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nvidia-vulkan-icd (= 375.82-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
```

How do I install the `nvidia-driver` with apt?

Comment: Debian 10 just exhibited the same problem, and adding "contrib' to sources.list fixed the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to enable the non-free repositories:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/stretch[^ ]* main$/& contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then run `apt update` and try your installation again. You’ll probably also need to install the kernel headers if you haven’t already:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

See [the full instructions on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by removing backports from sources

from this issue https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=906903

> We have had this before ... having both stretch and stretch-backports
>   enabled and trying to track stretch does not work currently for the
>   nvidia driver ... too many changes w.r.t. libglvnd etc.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Commented out `stretch-backports` from my /etc/apt/sources.list file

Answer (score 2):

Since this doesn't have an accepted answer yet, I'll go ahead and chip in what worked for me. I was having a very similar issue, with many of the same packages complaining, but there were an additional two `PreDepends` issues that `stretch-backports` was not resolving. Turns out, in addition to the instructions in the wiki page Stephen posted (https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers), I needed to add contrib for `stretch`. That is, in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I changed

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
```

to

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib
```

and ran `apt update`, after which i was able to install `nvidia-drivers` without issue.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! Note that I had already mentioned adding `contrib` ;-).

Comment: Totally missed that and somehow only saw the non-free there! Guess I need to read the code lines a little more carefully next time xP Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @jacaseyclyde I am surprised by your answer, saying that you need `contrib` repositories, since [`nvidia-driver` is in `non-free`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/nvidia-driver).

Comment: @Paradox I don't know why it worked, but it just worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under Debian 10 Buster and could solve it in two steps:

1. installing backport for corresponding Nvidia GForce 700 series as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).
2. There is somehow a bug related to DKMS and it could be solve by using experimental Debian packages which is described [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=972582).